# All the cursors are active and blinking, even after clicking on new Editable Text - EditableText Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a list of editableText in flutter, for different items, but When I click on a particular text cursor is blinking, but when I am clicking on other text, the previous cursor is still active.
[image]

```
eturn StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: snapshot,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var items = snapshot.data!.docs;

      List<dynamic> finalLists = firestoreFunctions.generateList(items);

      return ReorderableListView.builder(
        dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
        onReorder: ((oldIndex, newIndex) async {
          final finalIndex = newIndex > oldIndex ? newIndex - 1 : newIndex;

          firestoreFunctions.swapTasks(
              finalLists[oldIndex], finalLists[finalIndex]);
        }),
        itemCount: finalLists.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = finalLists[index];
          int len = finalLists.length;
          int fraction = 255 ~/ (len);
          int val = (255 - (fraction * index));
          Color colorRed = Color.fromRGBO((val), 0, 0, 1);
          Color colorBlue = Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, (val), 1);
          Color color = mainScreen ? colorRed : colorBlue;
          String title = item['title'];
          final TextEditingController editingController =
              new TextEditingController(text: title);

          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            key: ValueKey(item['id']),
            child: EditableText(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: title),
                focusNode: FocusNode(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.blue),
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                backgroundCursorColor: Colors.green),
          );

         
        },
      );
    }
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
```

Comment: This happens when all the EditableText have the same controller. check if this happens even if you remove the controller

Comment: @P4yam, I have taken different controllers, but still issue is the same